# pandas date range unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

I am plotting some data versus time, wanting the time to be on the x axis. In particular, it will be the period of time between the 3rd and 16th December 2014. The time is in the index of my dataframe, so I thought it would be straightforward. I checked the indexes and it looks fine:

```
IV.index[0]
Out[6]: Timestamp('2014-03-12 00:00:00')
IV.index[-1]
Out[5]: Timestamp('2014-12-16 00:00:00')
```

However, when I want to define my ticks as a date range, something really odd happens:

```
xticks1 = pd.date_range(start=IV.index[0],end=IV.index[-1], freq='7D', normalize=True)

xticks1
Out[8]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2014-03-12', '2014-03-19', '2014-03-26', '2014-04-02',
               '2014-04-09', '2014-04-16', '2014-04-23', '2014-04-30',
               '2014-05-07', '2014-05-14', '2014-05-21', '2014-05-28',
               '2014-06-04', '2014-06-11', '2014-06-18', '2014-06-25',
               '2014-07-02', '2014-07-09', '2014-07-16', '2014-07-23',
               '2014-07-30', '2014-08-06', '2014-08-13', '2014-08-20',
               '2014-08-27', '2014-09-03', '2014-09-10', '2014-09-17',
               '2014-09-24', '2014-10-01', '2014-10-08', '2014-10-15',
               '2014-10-22', '2014-10-29', '2014-11-05', '2014-11-12',
               '2014-11-19', '2014-11-26', '2014-12-03', '2014-12-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='7D')
```

I don't understand, why? I wanted My range of dates `['2014-12-03','2014-12-04' etc.]`

Actually, now I noticed, somehow the first date (third of December) got its month and day swapped! It is now the 12th of March! Does anyone have any idea how to fix this when I convert it to the datetime object? This is how I did it:

```
IV['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(IV['DATE'])
IV = IV.set_index("DATE")
```

Comment: You'll need to post what the original date strings actually looked like if they are just '2014-12-04' then you can do `IV['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(IV['DATE'], format='%Y-%d-%m')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the 'format' argument of pd.to_datetime. Observe:

```
>>> date = '2014-03-12 00:00:00'
>>> x=pd.to_datetime(date)
>>> x
10: Timestamp('2014-03-12 00:00:00')
>>> x.month
6: 3
>>> x=pd.to_datetime(date,format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
>>> x
7: Timestamp('2014-12-03 00:00:00')
>>> x.month
8: 12
```

pandas is assuming the format of the date to be %Y-%m-%d...